# How to make Ibeacon estimode detect all beacons with unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, estimote

I download the ibeacons asset store from the unity asset store I try to modify it so it can detect all the near estimote beacons because in the asset store I need to add the identified of the beacon so it can detect it, I want to make it detect all the nears beacons automatically without typing the beacon identified in the inputfield  [this is the script that I'm using](https://github.com/souleimagara/UpLoadeImages/blob/master/Example.txt) can anyone help me even a sample idea I have been searching for solutions from a long time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow !
Please take some time to follow the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions.
An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a summary of your researches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please insert important pieces of code in your question. That way you're making it much easier for people to answer!